# Can I sync events on Google Calendar one way?

Tags: google-calendar

I have two calendars, work and personal. I want things that I add to my work calendar to show up on my personal calendar as well - e.g. if I have an important meeting or work event it's relevant to both calendars. But I don't want everyone in my office to see if I'm meeting my partner for dinner, for example.

Is there any workaround that allows events to automatically be copied from one calendar to another, but not the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- You can transfer/share your work calendar to your personal email
  [like this](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/78739?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), and when you are logged in your personal account you
  can see your work calendar on the left side under "Other calendars." 
  [image]
- You can open both your work and personal Google calendars in
  Microsoft Office Outlook [like this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/See-your-Google-Calendar-in-Outlook-C1DAB514-0AD4-4811-824A-7D02C5E77126), and even overlay them on top
  of each other as it's shown [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/view-multiple-calendars-at-the-same-time-fffa8783-0556-4ea1-ba62-3ed8a95a903c). You can set this only on your personal computer at home.

[image]

Comment: The first solution works perfectly! If I add events to my work calendar they show up on my personal, but I can't see anything from my personal calendar on my work calendar. That's exactly what I wanted to happen. Thanks a bunch :).